# How to set the NZCV flags to constants in a single ARMv8 instruction

Tags: conditional-statements, arm64, armv8

I'd like to write a function that takes an ARMv8 instruction containing a condition code, and returns an ARMv8 instruction whose effect is the same as the original but with the condition inverted.

Most cases are easy:

- If the condition code is not `AL`, then just toggle bit 0 of the condition code.
- Otherwise (if the condition code is `AL`) there is no inverse condition code. Bizarrely `NV` behaves like `AL`! Instead we have to rewrite the instruction to pretend that its condition is always false:

  - If the instruction is a branch, replace it with a no-op.
  - If the instruction is `CSEL`, replace it with `MOV`.
  - If the instruction is `CSINC`, replace it with `ADD`.
  - If the instruction is `CSINV`, replace it with `MVN`.
  - If the instruction is `CSNEG`, replace it with `NEG`.
  - Otherwise it's `CCMP` or `CCMN`...

It's the last case that is causing me trouble. It doesn't matter whether the instruction is `CCMP` or `CCMN` since the arithmetic operation isn't going to happen anyway. What is needed is a way of setting the `N`, `Z`, `C` and `V` flags to arbitrary constant values in a single instruction. Is it possible?

Comment: While the question at hand is interesting, I think you're overthinking the `AL` case. After all, `ccmp w0, 0, 0, al` is really just `cmp w0, 0`, so there's nothing there to invert...

Comment: @Siguza The point is to reverse the instruction to `ccmp w0, 0, 0, nv` (using the imaginary `nv` "never" condition code). That version would clear all flags unconditionally.

Comment: Yes, but my argument is that no matter your point of reference, it should always be legal to substitute `ccmp w0, 0, 0, al` with `cmp w0, 0` and `b.al 0xabc` with `b 0xabc` without any change in behaviour. And if your set of rules does not require `cmp` and `b` instructions to be "inverted", then this would make the argument that neither do conditionals with `al`.

Comment: The exercise is not "How can I replace `ccmp w0, 0, 0, al` with something simpler." The exercise is "Given `ccmp w0, 0, 0, al`, how do I create an instruction that tests the opposite condition: If `al` is **false**, then compare `w0` with `0`; otherwise copy `0` to `nzcv`. `cmp` is not encoded with a condition code, so it is out of scope of the exercise. I agree that negating `b` shouldn't be in scope, since `b` is not shorthand for `bal`; it's a separate encoding.

Comment: Skimming all instructions in the architecture reference that set NZCV, I'm pretty sure this is not possible.  If you could use two instructions you could do `cmp wzr, #0 ; ccmp w0, 0, #nzcv, ne`.  If you could keep a GP register preloaded with `0x0123456789abcdef` then you could use `rmif` with a shift count selecting the desired nibble.